# Let's get involved with other SE sites!

Tags: discussion

I've looked at the profiles of many of the top users of this site, and I noticed something interesting.  Many of the contributors to this site do not participate in other SE sites. In particular, very few of the participants participate in *graduated, non-beta* SE sites.  I think this is a problem for the future of Islam.SE.  There is a lot of content on this site that does not really fit with the objectives of StackExchange, and I think that participating in established communities will help the users here understand exactly what level of quality is required in order to become a full site.

I would like to propose a challenge.  I want all of the users who are active here to choose one non-beta SE site and get involved with it. I'd also like to exclude StackOverflow since that site is huge and not really representative of the other SE sites. There are a lot of sites to choose from, and everybody should be able to find one on a topic that interests them. The list of the different sites is [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#). I would like for everybody here to join one of those non-beta sites and gain at least 1000 rep there. I think that that experience will really help out this community by allowing us to see how other sites work and to apply what we learn to building up this great site.

Obviously this is completely unenforceable and therefore optional, but I would really like it if people would at least give this a try.

Comment: Nah. Don't agree with the idea/notion. Rep are not representative of how much you know of other sites or how a site should be run/built.

Comment: @BleedingFingers You're right. When I say 1000 rep, I do not really intend for that particular number to be of particular importance. I just thought that was a good approximate number for someone to gain an appreciation for how things work.

Comment: Just that, it's not the only way to learn. And one can definitely learn without that. Simply read and loiter around. You know on [su] you can provide none technical answer but the same doesn't apply to questions. Pretty crappy. The mods their have ban hackentosh flat, the community was turned down flat.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is merit to this suggestion. A large number of the issues we are facing today is because we are attracting newcomers to the SE model, and it will take a load off the moderators if they are also on other SEs where they can see what is expected.